# use input value to perform calculation - Java applet

Tags: java, events, applet, calculator

I'm writing a Java applet for a programming class to calculate tuition. I think (no, I know) I've outkicked my coverage trying to get the ActionListener to get the input value and then use that value to perform the calculation. Code is below. This is homework, so I'm not looking for a bunch of code - I would just like to get pointed in the right direction for how to get the value a user would input into the "numCredits" text field incorporated into the tuition calculation formula. Thanks!

```
/**
 * Calculate tuition at NHCC based on 
 * number of credits and instruction type.
 * 
 * by Jodi Rehlander
 * version 1.0, 9/7/15 for CSci1130-51
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tuition4 extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
Image nhccImg;
ImageIcon nhccIcon;
JLabel credits, cType, nhcc, title; 
JTextField numCredits;
JButton online, standard, nursing;
JTextArea tType;
String inputCredits;
int numCreditsInt = 0;
double totalOnline;
double totalStandard;
double totalNursing;


    //define buttons, add listeners, display the buttons in the applet
    public void init( )
    {
        getContentPane( ).setBackground( Color.WHITE );

        setLayout( new BorderLayout( ) );

        nhccImg = getImage( getCodeBase( ), "NHCCLOGO.png" );
        nhccIcon = new ImageIcon( nhccImg );
        nhcc = new JLabel (nhccIcon);
        credits = new JLabel( "How many credits?" );
        cType = new JLabel( "\n What kind of classes?" );
        online = new JButton( "Online" );
        standard = new JButton( "Standard" );
        nursing = new JButton( "Nursing" );
        numCredits = new JTextField( "",3 );
        inputCredits = numCredits.getText( );
        tType = new JTextArea( 12,14 );
        tType.setEditable(false);
        addListeners( );
        add( nhcc, BorderLayout.WEST );
        JPanel pane = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( ) );
        pane.add( credits );
        pane.add( numCredits );
        pane.add( cType );
        pane.add( online );    
        pane.add( standard );     
        pane.add( nursing );
        pane.add( tType );
        add( pane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    }


     public void addListeners( )
    {
        numCredits.addActionListener( this );
        online.addActionListener( this );
        standard.addActionListener( this );
        nursing.addActionListener( this );
    }



    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae)
    {
        Object obj = ae.getSource( );
            if( obj == online )
            {
                numCreditsInt = Integer.parseInt(numCredits.getText( ) );
                tType.setText( "\n \n Tuition type: Online \n \n Cost/Credit: $177.96 \n Fees: $14.35 \n Textbooks: $250.00 \n \n Total Cost: " + "$"+( totalOnline ) );
            }
            else if ( obj == standard )
            {
                tType.setText( "Tuition type: Standard \n Cost/Credit: $165.08 \n Fees: $14.35 \n Parking: $3.20 \n Textbooks: $350.00 \n Total Costs: $xxx.xx \n" );
            }
            else if ( obj == nursing )
            {
               tType.setText( "Tuition type: Standard \n Cost/Credit: $189.78 \n Fees: $14.35 \n Parking: $3.20 \n Textbooks: $600.00 \n Total Costs: $xxx.xx \n" );
            }
            revalidate( );
            repaint( );
    }

    public double calculateOnlineTuition(int numCredits, double rate, double tuition, double fees, 
       double textbooks)
    {
        //calculate online tuition
        //numCredits = Integer.parseInt(inputCredits);
        rate = 177.96;
        fees = 14.35;
        textbooks = 275.00;
        tuition = numCreditsInt*rate;
        totalOnline = tuition + fees + textbooks;
        return totalOnline;

        //calculate Standard and Nursing rates once Online works
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint (g);

        Font heading = new Font( "Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 14 );
        Font small = new Font( "Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12 );
        Font smallItalic = new Font( "Monospaced", Font.ITALIC, 12 );


        g.setFont( heading );
        g.drawString("FEE BREAKDOWN:", 272, 375);
        g.setFont( small );
        g.drawString("Technology Fee    $8.00", 272, 390);
        g.drawString("Student Life Fee  $5.00", 272, 405);
        g.drawString("MSCSA Fee         $0.35", 272, 420);
        g.drawString("Health Svcs Fee   $1.00", 272, 435);
        g.drawString("*Parking          $3.20", 272, 450);
        g.setFont( smallItalic );
        g.drawString("*Parking not included", 280,485 );
        g.drawString("in online rate", 300,501);

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have an actionListener on `numCredits`  simply get the value when you click

Comment: [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: When the `actionListener` is triggered, you need to get the value for the number number of credits and call the `calculateOnlineTuition` method, passing it the required parameters based on the button that the use clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check to see if the `numCredits` field has a value or not, no point in making any calculations without out.

Next gather the require parameters for the `calculateOnlineTuition` method (FYI this smacks of a dedicated class by the way) based on the selected action.

There is no need for `numCredits` to have a `ActionListener`, as only the buttons have any meaning.  Also, it's pointless passing `tuition` to `calculateOnlineTuition` as this is the value you are trying to calculate, better to let the method simply return the value you're after

As an example:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Object obj = ae.getSource();

    if (!numCredits.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
        numCreditsInt = Integer.parseInt(numCredits.getText());
        double rate = 0;
        double fees = 0;
        double books = 0;
        if (obj == online) {
            rate = 177.96;
            fees = 14.35;
            books = 250.0;
            tType.setText("\n \n Tuition type: Online \n \n Cost/Credit: $177.96 \n Fees: $14.35 \n Textbooks: $250.00 \n \n Total Cost: ");
        } else if (obj == standard) {
            rate = 165.08 + 3.20; //?
            fees = 14.35;
            books = 350.0;
            tType.setText("Tuition type: Standard \n Cost/Credit: $165.08 \n Fees: $14.35 \n Parking: $3.20 \n Textbooks: $350.00 \n Total Costs: ");
        } else if (obj == nursing) {
            rate = 189.78 + 3.20; //?
            fees = 14.35;
            books = 600.0;
            tType.setText("Tuition type: Standard \n Cost/Credit: $189.78 \n Fees: $14.35 \n Parking: $3.20 \n Textbooks: $600.00 \n Total Costs: ");
        }

        double total = calculateOnlineTuition(numCreditsInt, rate, fees, books);
        tType.append(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(total) + "\n");

    }

    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

public double calculateOnlineTuition(int numCredits, double rate, double fees,
                double textbooks) {
    //calculate online tuition
    //numCredits = Integer.parseInt(inputCredits);
    rate = 177.96;
    fees = 14.35;
    textbooks = 275.00;
    double tuition = numCreditsInt * rate;
    totalOnline = tuition + fees + textbooks;
    return totalOnline;

    //calculate Standard and Nursing rates once Online works
}
```

Comment: >> this smacks of a dedicated class by the way << 

I was wondering about that. Would best practice be to create another class to hold the method? I'll have to figure out what that looks like. Appreciate the advice!

Comment: I'd create another class, which had properties for rate, fees and textbooks or what ever other "costs" you might need, I'd have a method which could take the numCredits and calculate the tuition, but that's me